# Rails 5 - routes and show page not hooking up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes, link-to

I am trying to set up a show page for a list of people in Rails 5, but having trouble getting the routes to sync.

config.route:

```
get '/team', to: 'pages#team'
get '/team/:id', to: 'pages#show', as: 'agent' #to get agent_path from rails routes
```

page_controller:

```
def team
 @admins = Admin.where(role: :staff)
end  

def show
 @admins = Admin.find(params[:id])
end
```

views/pages/team.html.erb:

```
<% @admins.each do |staff| %>
  <div class="team-link__inner">
    <div class="agent-image-team">
     <%= link_to (image_tag(staff.url, class: "team_link") agent_path(staff.id), class: "team-link") %>
    </div>
    <div class="hover-team-info">
      <p><%= staff.name %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

views/pages/show.html.erb: (sample to confirm routes)

```
<h1>Admin show page</h1>
<%@admins.each do |staff| %>
  <p><% staff.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

I've tried connecting my show pages up in a number of different ways, but keep getting errors when I try to set up my link in the index (team) view. What am I doing wrong?

errors are:

```
.../app/views/pages/team.html.erb:26: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')' class: "team_link") agent_path(staff.id), class: "team-link" ^ 
.../app/views/pages/team.html.erb:26: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' m_link") agent_path(staff.id), class: "team-link") );@output ^ 
.../app/views/pages/team.html.erb:26: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end aff.id), class: "team-link") );@output_buffer.safe_append=' ^ 
.../app/views/pages/team.html.erb:60: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input ensure ^
```

Comment: Are you missing a comma here: `...) agent_path...`? Should it be: `...), agent_path...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declaration of link_to is the problem. Try:

```
<%= link_to agent_path(staff.id), class: "team-link" do %>
   <%= image_tag staff.url, class: "team_link" %>
   # or
   <img src="#{staff.url}" class="team_link" />
<% end %>
```

Hope it'll solve the errors!

Comment: That did it! It took a bit of arranging to get the css to remain stable, but that was the last push I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

show route is used to display information of a single object

```
def show
 @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
end
```

And your view should just display the information of that particular object attributes (show.html.erb)

```
<h1>Admin show page</h1>
<p><%= @admin.name %></p>
```

Based on errors you are missing a comma, after the image tag closing brackets

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(staff.url, class: "team_link"), agent_path(staff.id), class: "team-link") %>
```

Comment: Right, and it would *also* work that way. Rails have a bigger problem with this line in the index view:   <%= link_to (image_tag(staff.url, class: "team_link") agent_path(staff.id), class: "team-link") %>

Comment: it would be easier if you could just post your errors with the question